# How to swap multiple elements based on their width on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many `.fidgrid--col` divs under the parent `#content-card` div. On window resize in tablet view, if the current div has greater width than the next div & if the next div can fit into the space before the current div, then i should be able to place it there.

In the below fiddle example, i want the order of the cards to be, 1-3-2-4-5-6-8-7. I have tried doing it with clone, but it is not working as expected. Can anyone of you please suggest how this can be done using Jquery on window resize. https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/2636/

Comment: try Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/